# Can I use APACHE mod_deflate with HTTPS TLS?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-deflate

My server is centos 7.4,with Apache 2.4.6,PHP 5.4,Mysql 5.5.
I plan to use `mod_deflate` to compress websites file as below:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
DeflateCompressionLevel 3
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE css js html htm xml  
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:pdf|mov|avi|mp3|mp4|rm)$ no-gzip dont-vary
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

I think everything is ok but when I read this [post](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html):

> Some web applications are vulnerable to an information disclosure attack when a TLS connection carries deflate compressed data. For more information, review the details of the "BREACH" family of attacks.

I am not a professional, I just want to know is there a way to safely use TLS HTTPS with compress function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be worth reading this SO question and answer to give you the why and what might work: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137182/enabling-sslcompression-in-apache